# Find the second derivative $\frac{dy}{dx}$ given a general function $G(x,y)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have a general function $G(x,y)$ where $x>0$ and $y>0$.
Let $G'_1$ and $G'_2$ denote $G'_1(x,y)=\frac{\partial G}{\partial x}$ and $G'_2(x,y)=\frac{\partial G}{\partial y}$ repectively. Similarly, let $G''_{11}=\frac{\partial ^2G}{\partial x^2}$ , $G''_{22}=\frac{\partial ^2G}{\partial y^2}$, $G''_{12}$ denote $G''_{11}(x,y)=\frac{\partial ^2G}{\partial x\partial y}$, $G''_{22}(x,y)$, $G''_{12}(x,y)$ respectively. Of course, by Young's Theorem, $G''_{12}(x,y) = G''_{21}(x,y)$
Knowing that $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{-G'_1}{G'_2}$$
How do I find $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$? In fact, I need to show that$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\frac{-\begin{bmatrix}G''_{11}\cdot(G'_2)^2+G''_{22}\cdot(G'_1)^2-2G''_{12}\cdot G'_1\cdot G'_2\end{bmatrix}}{(G'_2)^3}$$

Comment: What do $G_1$ and $G_2$ represent? It's unclear here.

Comment: Edited the question accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: It's still not 100% clear. Is $G_1'(x,y) = \frac{\partial G}{\partial x}$?

Comment: yes, you can say so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all
$$dG(x,y)=\frac{\partial G}{\partial x}dx+\frac{\partial G}{\partial y}dy=G'_1dx+G'_2dy$$
If you assume that $dG(x,y)=0$ then as you stated
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{G'_1}{G'_2}$$
For second derivative
$$d^2G(x,y)=\frac{\partial^2 G}{\partial x^2}(dx)^2+2\frac{\partial^2 G}{\partial x\partial y}dx\,dy+\frac{\partial^2 G}{\partial y^2}(dy)^2+\frac{\partial G}{\partial y}d^2y$$
$$=G''_{11}(dx)^2+2G''_{12}dx\,dy+G''_{22}(dy)^2+G'_2d^2y=0$$
By the first order condition
$$G''_{11}(dx)^2+2G''_{12}dx\,\bigg(-\frac{G'_1}{G'_2}\bigg)dx+G''_{22}\bigg(-\frac{G'_1}{G'_2}dx\bigg)^2+G'_2d^2y=0$$
and the last step
$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=-\frac{G''_{11}(G'_2)^2+G''_{22}(G'_1)^2-2G''_{12}G'_1G'_2}{(G'_2)^3 }$$